# knockout radio button checked status not updated in UI

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, radio-button

In my knockout application, I'm trying to handle a few radio inputs in a forEach loop.

The click event updated the checked properties, but the same is not reflected in the UI  of the radio button.

Below ID is the entire Dropdown html :

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu padding-left padding-right customscroll" data-bind="stoppropgattion:'ss'">

     <!--ko foreach:MyPlans-->
     <li>
        <div class="radio radio-adv">
        <label data-bind="attr:{for:$data.Id_$index}" for="cs_plan">
          <input class="access-hide" id="cs_plan" data-bind="value:$data.Selected,checked:$data.Selected,attr:{id:$data.Id_$index,name:true},click:UpdatedSelectedPlan" name="Plan" type="radio" />
          <span> <!--ko text:$data.Name--><!--/ko--><!--ko if:$data.IsDefault--><span> (Default)</span><!--/ko--></span><span class="circle"></span><span class="circle-check"></span>
        </label>
     </div>
   </li>
 <!--/ko-->
</ul>
```

And on clicking I'm updating the selected response also:

```
UpdatedSelectedPlan = function (data, event) {
            selF.MyPlans.filter(function (elem) {
                elem.Selected(false);
            });
            data.Selected(true);

        }
```

Selected value is updated properly, but the same is not reflected in the UI.

When the Dropdown loads the correct radio is shown as selected, but on click the clicked radio is not getting changed UI wise even though selected value is updated .

Please guide

Thanks

Shruti Nair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "change" event instead of "click". Radio and checkbox have change trigger.

```js
    function vm(){
    var self = this;
    self.MyPlans = ko.observableArray([
      {Id:1, Name:'A', Selected:ko.observable(false), IsDefault:true}, 
      {Id:2, Name:'B', Selected:ko.observable(false), IsDefault:false}, 
      {Id:3, Name:'C', Selected:ko.observable(false), IsDefault:false}, 
      {Id:4, Name:'D', Selected:ko.observable(false), IsDefault:false}, 
      {Id:5, Name:'E', Selected:ko.observable(true), IsDefault:false}, 
    ]);
      self.UpdatedSelectedPlan = function (data, event) {
            self.MyPlans().filter(function (elem) {
                elem.Selected(false);
            });
            data.Selected(true);
        }
                 
     }
     
     ko.applyBindings(new vm())
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul>
             <!--ko foreach:MyPlans-->
         <li>
            <div class="radio radio-adv">
            <label data-bind="attr:{for:$data.Id_$index}" for="cs_plan">
              <input class="access-hide" id="cs_plan" data-bind="checked:$data.Selected,value:$data.Selected,  attr:{id:$data.Id_$index,name:true},event:{change:$parent.UpdatedSelectedPlan}" name="Plan" type="radio" />
              <span> <!--ko text:$data.Name--><!--/ko--><!--ko if:$data.IsDefault--><span> (Default)</span><!--/ko--></span><span class="circle"></span><span class="circle-check"></span>
              selected ? <span data-bind="text:Selected"></span>
            </label>
         </div>
       </li>
     <!--/ko-->
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added return true to the method and it worked.

```
    UpdatedSelectedPlan = function (data, event) {
         selF.MyPlans.filter(function (elem) {
         elem.Selected(false);
    });
       data.Selected(true);
       return true;

   }
```